# Which head to position on before doing a merge?

Tags: mercurial, merge, dvcs, head

Is there a head to prefer when doing a merge?

What I mean is this: I've got, say, old rev 1000.  Meanwhile I did 234 commits and I'm at rev 1234.  Now I need to go back to rev 1000 to implement a bugfix for a customer.  I commit the bugfix, give the release to the customer, and have the commit 1235.

It's only a tiny change: affecting only one file.

At this point I have two heads: 1235 (whose parent is 1000) and 1234.  Their common (grand-grand-...-parent) is 1000.

If I issue an `hg merge` followed by an `hg status`, I receive a gigantic list of changes.

However if I do first `hg update -C 1234`, followed by an `hg merge` and an `hg status`, then I only see my unique change (unless I'm mistaken as to what just happened).

Basically, doing this:

```
hg update -C 1234
hg merge  # (merging 1234 and 1235, my two only heads)
hg status
```

gives a different status than this:

```
hg update -C 1235
hg merge  # (merging 1234 and 1235, my two only heads)
hg status
```

So basically, I'm asking the status (`hg status`) after merging the two same heads, but the output of `hg status` seems to depends on the head I'm currently at.

Is this the normal behavior and, if yes, is there one head to "prefer" over the other?

Do both operation result in the same repository / source code state at the end?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they both result in the same end state. Merges are almost 100% symmetric in Mercurial. The only non-symmetric part is *named branches*:

```
hg update branch-a
hg merge branch-b
hg commit
```

will create a changeset on `branch-a`. Updating to `branch-b` first will create it on `branch-b`. You can change the branch of the merge commit by issuing `hg branch` before you commit, though, so the default branch name more like a suggestion.

However, in your case, I would definitely update back to revision 1234 and then merge the bugfix into this revision. They way I'm thinking of it is that you have a main line of development — this is where you're working on new features for the next release.

When you make a bugfix to an old version you update back, make the bugfix, and make a bugfix release to your customer. You've then created another (tiny) branch for the bugfix. The question about where to update to before the merge is now this:

- do I want to continue along the bugfix branch? If so, then stay at the bugfix and merge the main branch into it.
- do I want to continue along the main branch? If so, then update back to the main branch and merge the bugfix branch into it.

In this case it only makes sense to update back to the main branch — you want your bugfix together with the new features, and you want to add more features.

Think about the named branches I mentioned above — there you would do

```
hg update 1.x
# fix bug
hg commit
hg tag 1.3
```

to go back to the 1.x series of your software, fix the bug, and make a 1.3 bugfix release. When done, you want to merge with the `default` branch. Since the branch name is inherited from the first parent in a merge, it's most smooth to update to default first:

```
hg update default
hg merge 1.x
hg commit
```

That's the [recommended way](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching) to do it in Mercurial.

Comment: +1, thanks a lot.  I did indeed went back to the main line of development and merge the bugfix back there.  But I was very surprised: the *"hg status"* (I always run *hg sta* before doing a commit) freaked me out...  So I kinda "deduced" that it was probably better to update to the main line and merge from there.  But still, I wanted to be sure I wasn't seeing things.  Somehow I was sure, since always, that the merge would always be 100% identical. I don't know where I got this from: it just seemed somehow logical to me... But I was wrong :) Thanks for the link, time to read!